# RecyclerView items in ArrayList

Tags: java, android

I am working on an android project and I am putting some TextViews inside a RecyclerView and at the same time I am trying to put those things in an array list as ViewHolder type. After some tests on the program i understood that the items that are inserted in the ArrayList are only the items that are shown in the screen. For example if my screen fits 15 textviews and i put 30 textviews inside the recycler view and arraylist, the size of the arraylist will be only 15 so i can't make any changes to the rest of the items.

Also when i scroll down the recycler view the arraylist get a size of the items that has been shown while scrolling but when i scroll back to the top and try to change the number of the TextViews and make them less the program crashes.

What i want is to have all of the items that have been added to the recycler view also in the arraylist in order to can use them.

Recycler View class code:

```
public class Tab1Child1Numbers extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Tab1Child1Numbers.ViewHolder> {

ArrayList<Integer> textFront;
ArrayList<Integer> textBack;
ArrayList<Integer> colors;
Context context;
ArrayList<ViewHolder> texts = new ArrayList<>();


public Tab1Child1Numbers(Context context, ArrayList<Integer> textFront, ArrayList<Integer> textBack, ArrayList<Integer> colors) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.textFront = textFront;
    this.textBack = textBack;
    this.colors = colors;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.tab1_child1_numbers, viewGroup, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {

    viewHolder.textFront.setText(textFront.get(i)+"");
    viewHolder.textBack.setText(textBack.get(i)+"");
    viewHolder.textFront.setBackgroundColor(colors.get(i));
    viewHolder.textBack.setBackgroundColor(colors.get(i));

    texts.add(viewHolder);
    // cardsFront.add(viewHolder.imageFront);
    // cardsBack.add(viewHolder.imgThumbnail);

    viewHolder.setClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {

            if (isLongClick) {

            } else {
                Deck deck = new Deck();
                deck.flipCard(texts.get(position).frame, texts.get(position).textFront, texts.get(position).textBack);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return textFront.size();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {

    public TextView textFront;
    public TextView textBack;
    public FrameLayout frame;
    public LinearLayout layout;

    private ItemClickListener clickListener;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textFront = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        textBack = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt2);
        frame = (FrameLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_frame);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    }

    public void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.clickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        clickListener.onClick(view, getPosition(), false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        clickListener.onClick(view, getPosition(), true);
        return true;
    }
}


class Deck {

    private void flipCard(View rootLayout, View cardFace, View cardBack) {


        FlipAnimation flipAnimation = new FlipAnimation(cardFace, cardBack);

        if (cardFace.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            flipAnimation.reverse();
        }
        rootLayout.startAnimation(flipAnimation);
    }

    public void flipAll(){

        System.out.println(texts.size()+"--------");
            randomize();
            for (int i = 0; i < texts.size(); i++) {
                flipCard(texts.get(i).frame, texts.get(i).textFront, texts.get(i).textBack);
            }

    }

    private void randomize(){

        for (int i=0; i<texts.size(); i++){

            if (texts.get(i).textFront.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                texts.get(i).textFront.setText(textFront.get(i) + "");
                texts.get(i).textFront.setBackgroundColor(colors.get(i));
            }

            else {
                texts.get(i).textBack.setText(textBack.get(i) + "");
                texts.get(i).textBack.setBackgroundColor(colors.get(i));
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to do something that you shouldn't.

`onBindViewHolder()` is called by the system whenever it is about to display a `ViewHolder` to the user. So it will initially be called once for every view on the screen, plus once for a small number of views just off-screen (so that they can scroll on screen nicely).

However, this means it will also be called repeatedly as the user scrolls through the data in your adapter. In these cases, the `ViewHolder` being passed to `onBindViewHolder()` might have been *recycled*, meaning it might previously have been used to display different data and is now being re-used to display new data.

Let's say you have one million items in your data set, but your layout is set up in such a way that only 15 items are visible on screen at any one time. Chances are good that the system will wind up creating about 20 `ViewHolder` instances (15 on the screen, 5 available for re-use just off-screen). These same 20 ViewHolders will be used to display all one million items if the user scrolls enough. They'll just keep being re-used over and over.

That's why this line is problematic:

```
texts.add(viewHolder);
```

You're going to wind up building a list with potentially millions of objects in it, with the same 20 `ViewHolder`s appearing multiple times in your list.

It would be much better to think about storing your data in a different way, rather than trying to store `ViewHolder`s passed to `onBindViewHolder()`.

Comment: I have already tried to figure out a way to store the viewHolders of each textView but i failed. Do you have anything to suggest?

Comment: Usually you should not have to store the `ViewHolder`s at all. You should instead have some sort of backing data (in your case, the three `List`s textFront, textBack, and colors) and just update that. Perhaps you need to make a fourth list. Perhaps it would be better to create some sort of new object to manage the text/color/etc for each item in your list. But all of this "meta" data should exist completely independently of the inner mechanics of your adapter and viewholders (the adapter should just set up the view based on your current data).

Comment: Yes, I understand what you are saying but in my case where I want to flip with animation all the TextViews that are inside the RecyclerView, how I would do that if i can't refer to the ViewHolders that i have already added in it?